Migration from cleveref to zref-clever
I want to try migrating from cleveref to zref-clever as it seems that cleveref has some problems with the latest developments in TeX and hyperref and is unlikely to receive an update.
My use of cleveref is not that extensive, I use only \cref \Cref and \cpageref (so far).
To try the migration, I put this in my preamble (more precisely, I created a style):
% \RequirePackage{cleveref} % old 

% Replaced by
\RequirePackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{
    abbrev=true, % To have the same default abbreviation behaviour
    }

% for easier migration:
\newcommand{\cref}[1]{\zcref{#1}}
\newcommand{\Cref}[1]{\zcref[S]{#1}}
\newcommand{\cpageref}[1]{\zcpageref{#1}}

My Questions regarding this:
a) Are there any differences to be expected from this use case? (I did not find any except the abbreviation option I had to add. But the manual of zref-clever was not so clear to me on where the differences to cleveref lie)
b) Has the approach to define \cref et al. with \newcommand problems? It allows me to easily switch back and forth between the two and I also prefer the capitalised \Cref at the beginning of a sentence over [S].
P.S. huge thanks to the authors of these packages for their efforts to provide and maintain the nice functionality!
